# Why won't the image display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so when the user types in 'snow shark' into the textbox 'movie' and presses search, the poster should pop up. It won't in the div that I put the img in. Why is this?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="movie" style="width: 400px; height: 20px; font-size: 120%; font-family: Verdana">
        <div id="search" style="text-align: center; width: 100px; height: 25px; position: absolute; left: 450px; top: 8.5px; cursor: pointer; background-color: #3366FF; color: white"> Search </div>
        <p id="donthavemovie"></p>

        <div id="movie_poster_div" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 20px; background-color: red"> <img id="movie_poster" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" src=""> </div>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#movie_poster_div').hide();
                })

                $('#search').click(function() {
                    $snowshark = $('#movie_poster').attr('src','http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81lqmCozYwL._SL1500_.jpg');

                    if($('#movie').val() == 'snow shark') {
                        $snowshark.fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                })
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does `$snowshark` = `$('#movie_poster_div')`?

Comment: By inspection, I don't think $snowshark has the correct value.  Could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure attr() does not return an element that you can use with fadeIn().  If you step into the code with a debugger, what do you see?

Comment: Assigning a variable to `$snowshark` was rather pointless, anyhow you'd do `var snowshark` not `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get what you mean by 'pop up', the following code can display img correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="movie" style="width: 400px; height: 20px; font-size: 120%; font-family: Verdana">
        <div id="search" style="text-align: center; width: 100px; height: 25px; position: absolute; left: 450px; top: 8.5px; cursor: pointer; background-color: #3366FF; color: white"> Search </div>
        <p id="donthavemovie"></p>

        <div id="movie_poster_div" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 20px; background-color: red"> <img id="movie_poster" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" src=""> </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#movie_poster_div').hide();
                })

                $('#search').click(function() {
                    $('#movie_poster').attr('src', 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81lqmCozYwL._SL1500_.jpg');

                    if($('#movie').val() == 'snow shark') {
                        $('#movie_poster_div').fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```